# Is the hadith about holding hands below the navel in Musannaf Abi Shaibah, Sahih?

Tags: hadith, salat, authenticity

I have found 2 Hadiths in Musannaf Abi Shaibah on which Hajrat Wahid ibn Hujur (R.A) says that Prophet holds hands below the navel is that hadith Sahih? Reference: Musannaf Abi Shaibah Hadith no: 3959. You can go to this pdf to get that hadith on page no.  715 last hadith of that page: https://www.ahlesunnatpak.com/uploads/musannaf%20ibn%20abi%20shaibah%201.pdf

> حدثنا وكيع، عن ربيع، عن أبي معشر، عن إبراهيم قال: «§يضع يمينه على شماله في الصلاة تحت السرة» ([source](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/4353))

> حدثنا وكيع، عن موسى بن عمير، عن علقمة بن وائل بن حجر، عن أبيه قال: «رأيت النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم §وضع يمينه على شماله في الصلاة»
> ([Source](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/4352))

Comment: Note that the hadith 3958 on your pdf says the same and there are even more in the following see for example [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/4356) and [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/4357).